# Interrupt a thread safely in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

There is a thread which connects to the server (HTTP) and waits for response or response timeout (server doesn't respond until it has data to return) in a loop. In case response returned a thread processing it.

On service stopping it is needed to stop/interrupt all threads but threads must finish response processing (in case a thread is processing and not just awaiting response).

Here is code example

```
public class WaitingResponseThread extends Thread {

    static final int TIMEOUT = 4 * 1000;
    static final int PROCESSING_DURATION = 2000;

    private volatile boolean stopped = false;
    private volatile boolean processing = false;

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("starting child thread");
        while(!stopped) {
            try {
                // here a thread is awaiting server response (in real life response timeout is 400 sec)
                // probably it is safe to interrupt the thread now
                // emulating this with Thread.sleep() 
                System.out.println("awaiting response");
                Thread.sleep(TIMEOUT);

                processing = true;

                // there is some job on response and we must allow it to finish the job
                // again emulating delay with Thread.sleep()
                Thread.sleep(PROCESSING_DURATION);

                processing = false;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("ending child thread");
    }

    public void setStopped(boolean stopped) {
        this.stopped = stopped;
    }

    public boolean isProcessing() {
        return processing;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WaitingResponseThread t = new WaitingResponseThread();

        // starting thread, it sends a request and waits for a response
        t.start();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(1);

            // let's allow the thread to finish normally in case it is processing response
            t.setStopped(true);

            System.out.println("awaiting child thread to get response");
            Thread.sleep(TIMEOUT + 1);

            // let's allow the thread to finish processing
            while(t.isProcessing()) {
                System.out.println("processing");
                Thread.sleep(500);
            }

            // we can't wait for 400sec until the next loop check
            // so as the thread is sleeping we just interrupting it
            if(t.isAlive()) {
                System.out.println("killing");
                t.interrupt();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("ending main thread");
    }
}
```

Is this "interrupt" method good? Is there another way not to wait as long as timeout and not to lose data being processed?

Comment: Try to look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)

Comment: An alternative would be to use Executors https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html Then you can call `yourPool.shutdown()` and `yourPool.awaitTermination(time, unit)` but you will still need to handle interruptions in each thread properly and as far as I am aware there is no cast iron way to ensure that threads always finish properly. Rather than reinventing the wheel.

Comment: The `interrupt` method is not a good choice if you still want to finish processing of current HTTP requests. The reason is that calling `interrupt` can cause an [`InterruptedIOException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InterruptedIOException.html) on IO operations on the thread being interrupted, terminating the attempt at IO (and HTTP requests involve IO)

Comment: @gumkins but you are starting just one single thread!? Where's the 'list of threads' you are talking about?

Comment: @isnot2bad, this is simplified example. Actually I was not trying to concentrate your attention on resource sharing between multiple threads. I just need to stop thread safely. But you can just imagine ArrayList<WaitingResponseThread> and its iteration for t.start(), t.setStopped(true), t.isProcessing() and t.interrupt() in main() method. For the sake of justice I modified subject and description but now I'm afraid somebody can ask why I need 1 thread :-)

Comment: @Erwin Bolwidt, response just arrived in case there is any change in business data. It is a kind of notification without having to create a connection per second and still to get notifications immediately after data modification.

Comment: @gumkins OK. So you have multiple threads and all of them behave as follows: Connect, wait, on time-out: reconnect, on success: process response and terminate. All threads are started at once and run in parallel. Your service main thread starts them and waits for them to complete. If the service is stopped, all threads should stop too, but finish data processing first in case they have already got a response to process. Is that correct?

Comment: @isnot2bad Yes, except that on response threads are not terminated but process response and send request again and wait for next response. Multiple threads are needed because each connects to different domain served by the same server.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
while(t.isProcessing()) {
    System.out.println("processing");
    Thread.sleep(500);
}
```

is a form of polling. You should avoid polling at all costs. If possible, use a form of delegation where the callee notifies the caller when it is done processing.

Other than that, I'm pretty sure interrupting a thread is something you also rarely want to do, but that the way you're doing it is fine if you have to do it anyway.

Comment: Hello Warkst! Yes, I know that. I just wanted to minimize code example. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The `Thread` class has a few functions that you can use when interrupting.

- Catching an `InterruptionException`
- Using the method `isInterrupted() (not static)`
- Using the method `interrupted() (static)`
- Checking `interrupted()` or `isInterrupted()` and then `throw new InterruptedException()`

With these you can probably make your thread finish the current job before killing it, probably within the catch clause.